# How do I set gdm monitor/display/screen setup to generic mirroring?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, gdm, gdm3

I have three displays and one TV connected to my computer. gdm (gnome display manager) somehow thinks that the main display is the TV. To circumvent the problem for all setups: How do I tell gdm to always mirror the main display to all connected displays. I am really wondering why this is not the default behavior of gdm anyway.

Copying the respective `monitors.xml` from `~/.config` to `/var/lib/gdm/.config` is not a valid solution, because the generated `monitors.xml` is not generic. It uses display names, serial numbers and so on. Creating a working generic `montors.xml` could be a solution.

Anybody an idea?

(Debian Stretch, gdm 3.22.3-3+deb9u2)